# How can I allow internal css to be allowed in Froala HTML WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: css, .net, froala

I am integrating Froala in my .net project . 
I have Few templates where there is an internal Css defined. How Can I allow Froala WYSIWYG to allow to use internal css , right now it just ignore the internal css defined. Is there any available plugin I am missing to allow internal css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor has a built-in mechanism for preventing XSS attacks. By default, the style tag is removed, as well as the script one (see [this](https://wysiwyg-editor.froala.help/hc/en-us/articles/115000428829-Why-is-the-script-tag-being-removed-) for more details). To allow it, you'd have to remove the style tag from the [htmlRemoveTags option](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#htmlRemoveTags).